# Image search on FilePicker.io

Tags: android, filepicker.io

Okay, I am using https://www.filepicker.com/ in order to build my app. For the web version and in the  iOS version of the file picker, it has the option to make an image search. But for the android version of the file picker, it doesn’t. Do you have some walk around for this issue?

Any helps are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have emailed then and they said "unfortunately there’s no workaround for this at the moment. This is something that we need to add to our android client. We are planning to do so, but right not I’m not able to give you any specific date.".

We will have to wait